# Bootstrap label display issue when using vue-component

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, label, vue-component

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNwpY.png)

Look at the red labels, rendered with vue-component. They suppose to act the same as green labels, rendered with blade-template. Why there's a difference?

Blade template:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">

    <span class="label label-success">good badge 1</span>
    <span class="label label-success">good badge 2</span>
    <span class="label label-success">good badge 3</span>
    <span class="label label-success">good badge 4</span>
    <span class="label label-success">good badge 5</span>

    <badge-list></badge-list>

    <span class="label label-success">good badge 6</span>
    <span class="label label-success">good badge 7</span>

</div>
<div class="col-sm-10">
    some text</br>
    some text</br>
    some text</br>
    some text</br>
    some text</br>
    some text</br>            
</div>
```

Vue-component:

```
<template>
    <span  v-for="Badge in Badges" class="label label-danger">{{ Badge.name }}</span>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      Badges: [
        {"name": "bad badge 1"}, 
        {"name": "bad badge 2"}, 
        {"name": "bad badge 3"}, 
        {"name": "bad badge 4"}, 
        {"name": "bad badge 5"},
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual explanation for this is strange:

When you type your HTML, you press 'enter' / 'return' to create a new line (which inserts an invisible character if you will) after each `<span>` element.

For the elements constructed with Vue (or JavaScript in general for that matter), the returns aren't present, and, thus, the trailing space is not inserted.

Chris Coyier eloquently describes the options for space removal in [this article](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

The solution is to override the Bootstrap CSS for labels:

```
.label {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation!

Comment: &NewLine; is just as valid but doesn't require overriding any Bootstrap CSS which could lead to issues elsewhere in your project. See @Denis Pugachev's answer

Answer (score 1):

You may use `&NewLine;` HTML entity like:

```
<template v-for="Badge in Badges">
    <span class="label label-danger">{{ Badge.name }}</span>&NewLine;
</template>
```

Comment: I like this answer because it doesn't involve overriding Bootstrap values in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Change label CSS from "display: inline" to "display: inline-block".

Comment: I've explained why you need to add `inline-block` in my answer. If you found it helpful, please mark it as accepted and vote it up :-)